# how to serialize a specific json format

Tags: java, json, list, serialization

I need to set json in a format provided below.

```
"Tyre": {
    "title": "Tyre",
    "cls": "TyreCondition",
    "items": [
      {
        "firstItem": [
          {
            "title": "Front right tyre",
            "value": "50%",
            "subValue": "30,000 km Approx"
          }
        ],
        "secItem": [
          {
            "title": "title",
            "value": "Front right tyre tread - 50%"
          },
          {
            "title": "title",
            "value": "Front right tyre tread - 50%"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

class that i have created for this is looks like:

```
private String title;
private String cls;



@SerializedName("firstItem")
private List<UsedCarInspectionInfo> items;
@SerializedName("secItem")
private List<UsedCarTyreImage> imageList;
//getter and setter
```

when i run this code with this class structure, I am getting the json like-

```
"Tyre": {
"title": "Tyre",
"cls": "TyreCondition",
"firstItem": [
  {
    "title": "Front right tyre",
    "value": "50%",
    "subValue": "30,000 km Approx"
  }
],
"secItem": [
  {
    "title": "title",
    "value": "Front right tyre tread - 50%"
  },
  {
    "title": "title",
    "value": "Front right tyre tread - 50%"
  }
]}
```

Any idea how i can get the firstItem and secItem array in Items array?

Answer (score 2):

You get no `items` key in your JSON, because you override the `items` field in your Java class with `@SerializedName`.

You need something like this:

```
String title;
String cls;
List<Item> items;


static class Item {
  List<FirstItem> firstItem;
  List<SecItem> secItem;
}

static class FirstItem {
  String title;
  String value;
  String subValue;
}

static class SecItem {
  String title;
  String value;
}
```

Comment: when i need to add values to the items list,how i will be able to add the values of two different type lists into another one.

Comment: @divyanshugupta It's just Java code. If you always only got a single element in `items` you could just do `items.get(0).getFirstItem().add(anotherFirstItem)`

Comment: List<Items> items = new ArrayList<Items>(); 
items.get(0) this would be a null pointer

Comment: You of course have to `add` some Item before you can `get` it from the list.

Comment: I have List<FirstItem> firstItem and List<SecItem> secItem; with data.now i need to set this data into List<Items> item. this is the actual problem i am facing

Comment: I guess you're missing the Java basics. Just do `items = new ArrayList<>(); Item item = new Item(); item.setFirstItem(firstItem); item.setSecItem(secItem); items.add(item);`

Comment: Thanks for help buddy,it was silly mistake i was making to write the code. #Workexhaustion